# Is a miracle still a miracle if it took a long time for it to happen?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Suppose $t=0$ to be the moment of Big Bang. From then on an event has been "trying" to happen every second. The probability of it happening in a time duration of $1s$ is $10^{-10}$. And this probability 'resets' every second. So the probability of it happening in the time interval $t=0$ to $t=1s$ is $10^{-10}$. It is again $10^{-10}$ from $t=1s$ to $t=2s$ and so on.

Suppose the event happens for the first time in the time interval from $t=10^{20}s$ to $t=(10^{20}+1)s$.

It took $10^{20}s$ for it to happen. The probability of it not happening in $10^{20}$s is $(1-10^{-10})^{10^{20}}\approx e^{-10}$ which makes the probability of it happening in $10^{20}s$ almost $1$. From this point of view,  it seems no 'big thing' that the event has happened in $10^{20}s$.

However, just before the event happened, we know from gambler's fallacy that the fact that it did not happen in the last $\approx10^{20}s$ is not going to affect the odds of it happening in the future. The probability of it happening in the next few moments is the same old $10^{-10}$. From this point of view, it indeed seems like a miracle that such an event of very low probability has happened.

Comment: You already did the calculations, you would call it a miracle if you would a priori predict it to happen in the next second. However, with $10^{20}$ trials it is not. You can also use the Poisson approximation to see this.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: @littleO It doesn't seem like a miracle from the point of view that  the chance of it happening in $10^{20}s$ was already very close to 1. So, it's no surprise that it happened in that time interval. But if we switch our point of view to moments before the event happened, at that point the chance of it happening is $10^{-10}$. So, from this point of view it is a miracle that such a low probability event happened. So, was the happening of this event a miracle according to the second point of view or was the event bound to happen according to the first point of view?

Comment: Deal out a bridge hand (13 cards) from a deck of 52. Whatever hand you deal out, the probability that you would deal out that exact hand, before you dealt it out, was awfully close to zero. So, is it a miracle that you dealt out exactly that hand?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Mathematically, I think yes. My definition of miracle is just an event of awfully low probability (and not something whose occurrence can't be explained by natural causes).

Comment: So every time there's a bridge tournament, there are hundreds of miracles? Seems to cheapen the notion of "miracle", if there can be so many of them.

Comment: I've edited my answer...

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh yes, Miracles, by this definition, happen all the time. But if you guessed the outcome before they happen, it would take a miracle for your guess to be true. And if you picked a miracle and waited for it to happen, you might have to wait more than the age of the universe.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It's similar to : Someone wins the lottery every week. The event that "a winner is declared today" is no miracle for you. But if you're that winner, it'd be a miracle for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that the event happens in the time interval $(10^{20},10^{20}+1]$ is $$10^{-10}$$
a very small number. It is a mirackle if it happens...

The probability that this is the first occurrence is$$\left(1-10^{-10}\right)^{10^{20}}10^{-10},$$
a very small number again. So, it is an even greater miracle...

On the other hand $$1-\left(1-10^{-10}\right)^{10^{20}}$$
is, indeed, very close to $1$.  But this is the probability that the event has happened at least once so far (until the $10^{10^{20}}$th moment), but not the probability that it happens now in the $10^{10^{20}}$th moment.

Perhaps the argumentation above resolves the mistery.

So, we have three miracles:

(1) The event has not yet happened so far.

(2) The event happens exactly now and never before.

(3) It happens exactly now independently of the past.

Is there any contradiction?

To answer the question in the title of the OP.

Yes, it it is still a miracle that the event happens in a given time slot even if it is not a miracle that the even has taken place if enough time has gone by.

Comment: $(1-10^{-10})^{10^{20}} $ is not very close to 1 as you have written, it's actually almost 0. This is the probability that the event didn't happen in $10^{20}s$ even once. So, the probability that it happened in $10^{20}s$ is almost 1.

Comment: @RyderRude: Yes, thank you. I mistakenly "saw" 1 minus of the same. (Shame on me.)